# Tabulator pagination: stop groups from being cut between pages

Tags: tabulator

I haved this Tabulator table with grouped rows.
Pagination is activated.

Say page size is 5.
If I have a group of 3 rows and a group of 2 rows, then I see:

- the header for group 1
- the 3 rows of group 1
- the header for group 2

I have to go on the next page to see the 2 rows of group 2 (with no header)

How can I make sure row groups are not cut this way?
I'd like to find a way to tell Tabulator: "if a group cannot fit into a page, then start it on next page"
Of course I guess that would be a problem if a group would be larger than the page size, but then an error would be fine (or I guess I could check that before setting the page size)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with Tabulator. When using pagination in Tabulator you define a page size in a number of rows.

This counts as the number of visible row elements, which includes normal rows, group headers and calculation rows.

The reason for this is to create a smoother user experience by ensuring that each page has the same number of visible rows and maintains the same height.

If the table changes height every page because it contains a different number of elements, it would cause the pagination buttons to move about which would be jarring for the user.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to use some padding to avoid height variation? I mean when avoiding page break within a group would mean having missing rows, then add empty rows to avoid height change

Comment: I would not consider it to be a good user experience to do this, I would re-evaluate why I am looking for the particular functionality in the first place and consider what information I actually needed to display to the user